# 20 amp wires into 15 amp outlet

Tags: electrical

I'm replacing a hall way outlet that only runs the hall light. I have the 15 amp outlet and the wires coming out of wall are too big to fit in holes. Guessing 20 amp? Is it ok to just wrap them around screws instead? thanks

Comment: What's the rating of the circuit breaker that powers the outlet? I don't like the idea of a 15A outlet on a 20A circuit. I know you only plan use it with the hall lamp but the next occupant might plug in a hair dryer and a curling iron and a coffee percolator and a toaster and melt the outlet and even if you don't get blamed it will still be your fault.

Comment: You might consider whether you're the person for the job if you don't know what wire gauge is. Some basic electrical knowledge is crucial for safety, both during and after your work.

Comment: @A.I.Breveleri There's no problem using 15 ampere receptacles on a 20 ampere circuit. See [this answer](http://diy.stackexchange.com/a/12125/33) for more details.

Comment: 15A outlet on a 20A circuit is specifically allowed in the code as a special exception. UL listed 15A outlets are safe to handle 20A thru.

Comment: Tester and Wolf -- I am an electrical engineer and I am sometimes tempted to think I am an electrician. Thank you for helping me remember that I am not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

”15A” outlets refers to them being shaped to only accept '.' NEMA 5-15 plugs, not the -.' NEMA 5-20 plugs. They are code legal in 20A circuits.  This does not make it ok to cheat a 20A device into a 15A plug, because the plug pins may not be rated for 20A.

If it bothers you, it's legal  to change the breaker to 15A or fit 5-20 outlets.  Be glad  you have 12ga wire throughout.  14ga is for the birds, I do not use it.

If you like safety, use screw terminals.  Poke holes (often called backstabs) are designed merely to save $$$ in installation time.  The mechanism which grabs the wire may seem magical, but bust an outlet apart and you will be appalled at how chintzy it is.  Remember these outlets wholesale for 38 cents.

If doing 4 screw terminals per outlet in awkward positions doesn't sound like fun, google "pigtailing".  Makes things easy, you can do the pigtails at an ergonomically suitable workbench.

Also wrap the outlet (top, bottom and both sides) with a couple loops of electrical tape to cover the screws.

When you're the homeowner, you have the time to do it well.  Also it impresses inspectors.

Answer (score 5):

That's exactly what you're supposed to do.  The back stab terminals on receptacles are designed only to accept #14 wire, and typically are labeled as such.

If you're using #12 wire, you'll have to use the screw terminals. Keep in mind, however, that you can only connect one wire per screw terminal.

Comment: +1 The wires fall out of the 'holes' and arc more commonly than they'll ever come off the screws.