# Is this 15 amp w/2usb outlet on a 20 amp circuit against code? Does it present a fire hazard?

Tags: electrical

So the 15/20 amp circuits are confusing, from my reading you can have a 20 amp breaker with 12g wire and multiple 15 amp receptacles because the total draw of all receptacles combined might exceed 15 amps.

However, you can't have a single 15 amp outlet on a 20 amp circuit, because then the outlet might overheat if it draws more than 15 amps instead of the breaker tripping. For the purposes of this, a duplex receptacle is considered two separate receptacles.

I'm thinking about putting an outlet like this in for my garage. Does the addition of two USB outlets count a "Seperate receptacle" for the purposes of the above guidlines?

For the purpose of this question, I'm asking from Kansas.

[image]

Comment: There is a very similar question/answer here:

http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/12115/is-using-15-amp-components-on-a-20-amp-breaker-against-code

Comment: The previous question is actually where I got most of my info, however it is not a duplicate. This question is specifically about weather the above outlet counts as a duplex for the purposes of code standards.

Comment: The confusing point for most people with 15/20 amp recpt's is the face.  Most are 20 amp devices and can be used with 12ga wire and a 20 amp breaker.  Two parallel blades over a ground is a 15 amp recpt face. To see what a 20 amp recpt face looks like click the last link in @sean's answer.

Answer (score 2):

I believe it does, based on the 2011 NEC (which I believe applies to you?)

Definitions used are available [here](http://nfpa.typepad.com/files/70-14article100.pdf)

A strict interpretation of "receptacle" and "attachment plug" would make that a multiple receptacle.

There are 20 amp versions of that available; [here for example](https://www.google.com/shopping/product/10949952594376277307?q=20%20amp%20usb%20outlet&espv=2&biw=1920&bih=974&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.&bvm=bv.139782543,d.eWE&ion=1&tch=1&ech=1&psi=r_E1WOLwOcrYmwHs45O4Cg.1479930288865.5&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjisOaC0r_QAhXGQSYKHVtqCWQQqA0IHigE)